# Percentage of mixture of paint I have mixed?

Tags: percentages

Hi this probably seems an obvious question, for which I apologise.

I have recently mixed 300ml of paint with 150ml of water.
So 450ml total mixture

Can anyone tell me the mix ratio and percentage.?

In assuming it's not 50/50 because that would be 300ml water and 300ml paint

So I was confusing myself as 150ml is 50% of the 300.

I'd be greatfull to know how to work these out properly In the future as well as it's a long time and I've forgotten.

Thanks again

Comment: 150 is 50% of 300, but the total is not 300, it is 450. 150 is 33.3% of 450.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed a recipe that told you to mix in this ratio, that recipe might have said to mix in a ratio of $2:1$. It's a pretty common way to phrase it (alternatively, something along the lines of "Add two parts paint and one part water" if they were writing it out with words). That sounds like $50\%$ water, but the amount of water is $50\%$ of the amount of paint, not $50\%$ of the total amount of mixture.

There is $150ml$ water, and the total volume of the mixture is $450ml$. That means that the mixture contains $33\frac13\%$ water (assuming the raw paint didn't have any water in it already, as that would muddle things up a little bit).

Answer (score 0):

$300$ ml paint in $450$ ml solution makes it:

$$66.67\% \text{ paint and } 33.33\% \text{ water }$$